# java generics - convert List<object> to List<T>

Tags: java, generics

I have a class `MySpecialClass <T extends Comparable<T>>`

I am trying to to do the following:

`toItemList()` -> should take `List<Dog>` and convert it to `List<T>` so the `MySpecialClass` can operate on it.

`fromItemList()` -> should take in memory `List<T>` and convert it to List of objects. So if I have List it should convert it to `List<Dog>`, so I can get a back conversion after all operations are done.

How do I construct something like that in Java? My `MySpecialClass` works with `List<T>` which is why I need that.

```
public List<T> toItemList(List<dogs> list or List<cats> list){
// how to convert?      

    }



public List<dog> or List<cat>  fromItemList(){
      //local _inMemoryList (which is List<T>) convert to List<dog> or List<cat> depending on what MySpecialClass T is   
 // how to convert?     

        }
```

PS I am very new to java, always worked with .net so don't judge :)

Comment: Could you please describe it more? Like what is the signature of these 2 methods: `toItemList()` and `fromItemList()` ?

Answer (score 5):

I think you're mis-understanding what the `<T>` is doing in your example. T is a placeholder for any other class that implements Comparable.

Let's take a quick look at how this'll work, using your definition above of MySpecialClass.

```
public class Dog implements Comparable<Dog> {

}

public class Cat {

}
// This works because Dog implements Comparable
MySpecialClass<Dog> x = new MySpecialClass<Dog>();

// This will not because Cat does not implement Comparable
MySpecialClass<Cat> x = new MySpecialClass<Cat>();
```

There are many good tutorials for how to use generics in Java, probably starting with the [Oracle tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genmethods.html).

Comment: I get an error when I do the following: MySpecialClass<Dog> x = new MySpecialClass<Dog>();
Bound mismatch: The type Dog is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<T>> of the type MySpecialClass<T>

Comment: also when I add Dog implements Comparable I get "Comparable is a raw type. References to generic type Comparable<T> should be parameterized"

Comment: I actually created all 3 classes in Eclipse - MySpecialClass, a Main, and Dog and edited my example appropriately. The only change was that in the Dog class I had to make sure that I said `implements Comparable<Dog>`. If that still doesn't fix it for you, I'll post my full code example.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you didn't understand generics. In generic Class definition T stands the Type parameter so you can send cat, dog whatever you want as long as it extends Comparable in your class example. Here is an implementation of the fromItemList as I understand:

```
List<Object> fromItemList(List<T> list){

}
```

there is no need to have toItemList method as you have the Type

Comment: What does that actually accomplish? Doesn't every T have to extend Object? The method you suggest would simply return list immediately.

Comment: That's what I do understand from his question

Comment: and that would be List<Dog> fromItemList(List<T> list){ [how to actually convert though?] }

Comment: List<Object> objList=new ArrayList<Object>();
objList.addAll(fromItemList);